# In Avatar, does Ninat refer to Ninet Tayeb, Israeli singer?

Tags: plot-explanation, avatar

In the movie Avatar, Neytiri refers to "Ninat" as being the best singer, this sounds awfully similar to Ninet Tayeb, the first person to win on Israel's version of American Idol. (Supposingly, the "best singer").

Is it possible that they are related?

Comment: You're not the only person to notice this:  http://james-camerons-avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Ninat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest, my initial answer would have been 'no', but one of the songs on the credits was done by Leona Lewis (who won the 3rd series of X-factor in the UK) so it could be a possible head nod

(Disclaimer, I hate the Xfactor and try to avoid it where possible...)   :)